# Ruby gems - how to install required package with version. requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am running ubuntu 12.04 and I get the below error when trying to install.  How do I resolve?
How ot I get ruby 1.9.1?
This is how I install on ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev libopenssl-ruby rdoc ri irb build-essential wget ssl-cert
sudo apt-get -y install rubygems


sudo gem install knife-windows --include-dependencies
INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed
INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list
ERROR:  Error installing knife-windows:
    gssapi requires Ruby version >= 1.9.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Ubuntu to test it right now, but I think `ruby` may be an alias for `ruby1.8-full`.

Try installing `ruby1.9.3`, or similar. You can check the [full packages list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ruby/).